# EOFException when reading a url address

Tags: java

This is my code to read URL that sent from client:

(Server Class)

```
Socket serverS = serverSocket.accept();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(serverS.getInputStream())

   if(in.readUTF().equals("http://localhost:8181")){
      // do something
      }
```

But it has an exception:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at myp.T3Server.run(T3Server.java:37)
```

I write as `UTF` in client class.

**update**

client class:

```
        Socket client = new Socket(serverName, portNumber);
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        out.writeInt("http://localhost:8181/pic");
        client.close();
```

server class:

```
   Socket serverS = serverSocket.accept();
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(serverS.getInputStream());
     if (in.readUTF().equalsIgnoreCase("http://localhost:8181")) { 
         System.out.println("its http://localhost:8181");
           serverS.close();
         } else if (in.readUTF().equals("http://localhost:8181/pic")) {  //Error here
           System.out.println("its pic");
            serverS.close();
         }
```

Result:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at myp.T3Server.run(T3Server.java:37)
```

Comment: That code throws the error or what? Probably there's nothing else to read and you get such exception.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't writing a UTF String on the Server. Also, is the remote server writing the url for some reason?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I write as UTF in my client class

Comment: There isn't even a short (containing the number of following UTF-8 bytes) to be read. - How do you connect and write?

Comment: Well, you use `writeInt` when you should use `writeUTF` from your client...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza see update again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i changed code, The Error is occur on `else if (...)` statement.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense why you got the exception: your client only sends one message but you're reading it twice on server.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I think that my problem is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you expect one (1) String, but your code

```
  if (in.readUTF().equalsIgnoreCase("http://localhost:8181")) {    // !!!!!!
     System.out.println("its http://localhost:8181");
       serverS.close();
     } else if (in.readUTF().equals("http://localhost:8181/pic")) {  // !!!!!
       System.out.println("its pic");
        serverS.close();
     }
```

reads two (2) Strings if the first isn't the expected value. Do this:

```
String reply = in.readUTF();
if( "http://localhost:8181".equalsIgnoreCase( reply ) ||
    "http://localhost:8181/pic".equalsIgnoreCase( reply ) ){
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
in.close();
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick read on this: [Class EOFException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) and you will probably figure out that the stream you're reading is empty.

Answer (score 0):

While reading from the file, your are not terminating your loop
Throws:

EOFException - if this input stream reaches the end before reading eight bytes.

IOException - the stream has been closed and the contained input stream does not support reading after close, or another I/O error occurs.

Comment: Terminate which loop? Eight bytes? Which question did you answer?